# How can I debug a referenced dll from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dll

In Visual Studio 2012 I have two projects in the same solution, say A and B.

B is a project which I finished coding some time ago. In project A, I need to use some classes from the project B. To do so, I added a reference for B in A.

The problem is when I try to debug. I want to be able to step into B's code as well. haw can I do it?

I already copied dll and pdb files in A, but without result.

Comment: i have one solution with two projects

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this would not work.  However, the debugger is likely to have trouble locating the source code for projects that are in the other solution.  Right-click the solution A node, Properties, Debug Source Files, add the directory.  And remove anything in the "Do not look in" box, entries are added there when you clicked Cancel when the debugger asked you to locate the source file.

Comment: in my project "A" I run an .exe with a line command, this command contains calls to some class in the solution "B", I think it's because of this that debugging does not work

Comment: "Does not work" does not help us help you, you must tell us exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: in my B project i have this message : the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document attach process.  knowing that I added .pdb and .dll files

Comment: I have no error messages,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referencing project B by adding a reference to the .dll, not the project. In project A, right click References -> Add Reference. Then select project B under the Solution tab, not the .dll from the Assemblies tab.

Answer (score 0):

Undo all you did trying to reference B, after that go to A>References>Add Reference
In the windows opened select "Solution" (left panel) so you'll see all solution's projects, then select (check) the project B. Compile and debug.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions but this worked for me.

1. In solution property -> Debug Source Files, make sure the files are not in the 'Do not look for these source files' box.
2. In Tools -> Options -> Debugging, un-check Require source files to exactly match the original statement.
3. Rebuild and Copy dll and pdb files from library project bin folder to referenced project bin folder.
4. Uncheck Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code option.
5. Make sure the symbols are loaded correctly:
   During Debug, when it comes to a breakpoint, use Debug | Windows | Modules. Find the target dll file and making sure its Symbol Status is Symbol Loaded.